# Using sendgrid how to know whether my email bounced or get succesfully delivered in my code

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid

I am using Sendgrid npm module for sending emails to my customers with node.js, now i am facing a problem here, when i send an email to an email which does not exist then my email is getting bounced but in my response on my server code i am getting "success" but on my sendgrid's dashboard it is showing me email as bounced, now can anyone please tell me how can i know in my code that whether my code bounced or successfully sent.

My code is given below

```
var options = {
        auth: {
            api_user: 'abc',
            api_key: 'pass'
        }
    }

    var mailer = nodemailer.createTransport(sgTransport(options));

    var email = {
        to: email_id,
        from: 'noreply@abc.com',
        subject: 'ABC Verification Code',
        text: "Your ABC Verification Code is " + totp
//        html: '<b>Awesome sauce</b>'
    };

    mailer.sendMail(email, function(err, res) {
        if (err) { 
            console.log(err);
            res.json({success : 0, message : "Sorry Please try Again"});
            return next();
        } else {
            console.log('res: ', res);
            res.json({success : 1, message : "Successfully Sent Otp To Email Id"});
            return next();
        }
    });
```

Also one more question here when i am sending my email using unsubscribed group id then my email is always getting delivered in gmail's "promotions" section can anyone please tell me how can i show my email to user in gmail's "updates" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SendGrid API is asynchronous. Your request is accepted and then goes through several stages of processing including delivery. The API requests would take a very long time to respond if they had to wait for delivery to be attempted.

You have two options. The best option is to use the [event webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html) to receive events in real-time. There is some [nodejs event webhook sample code](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/Webhook_Examples/nodejs.html#-Event-Webhook):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

app.post('/event', function (req, res) {
  var events = req.body;
  events.forEach(function (event) {
    // Here, you now have each event and can process them how you like
    processEvent(event);
  });
});

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

Or you can poll your suppression lists via API, using e.g. the [bounces](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/bounces.html) endpoint.

There is no way to control which tab gmail uses to display your message, it's based on Google's analysis of the content of the messages and your sending habits.

Comment: Event webhook link no longer works. I don't know what was the exact content of that page so here's a similar page in the docs:
https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event